# Meteor js imports

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I built my first application in meteor.js using blaze.js as a complete noob and the application is in need of some TLC. I've updated to 1.4 and with that I assumed I need to change the directory structure, as discussed on the meteor js website and add in import/export for load order.

If eager loading and lazy loading are still running how do I find out what I need to import? I'm still wrapping my head around this so if the question is obvious please be kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eager loading is still running, as you've discovered, so we're still in a transitional period. to answer your question, "what do i need to import?", it depends on how you look at it.

in one sense, you need import nothing, because it's still eagerly loaded.

or you can move one of your files into /imports, and now the answer is: whatever is in that file that is needed by something else.

i recently went through a big effort to move all our server code into /imports, and it was pretty straightforward. (a couple gotchas, but all the collections, methods, publishes, and consts went smoothly).

i simply picked one app-level concept (let's say it was bacon), created a folder:

```
/imports/api/bacon
```

... and one by one moved the shared and server files into there or a subdirectory of there. with each move, i figured out which symbols were used externally, converted the file to an ES15 module, exported those symbols, searched through the code to see where they were used, and added an import statement as needed.

i hadn't used ES15 module syntax before, but the Meteor guide was sufficiently clear and i got it done in a couple days, testing as i went.

i use Webstorm for my IDE, and it's good about code-hinting and marking unknown symbols, so that helped.

for my example above, my directory structure is roughly:

```
/imports/api/bacon (collection and consts go here)
/imports/api/bacon/utils (shared utilities go here)
/imports/api/bacon/server (publishes and methods go here)
/imports/api/bacon/sever/utils (server utilities go here)
```